# nav выходит за пределы div

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Появилась проблемка: nav выходит за пределы div при масштабирование окна браузера. Пытался я её решить, так и не смог.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@charset "utf-8";
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0 none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

address,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

a,
a:hover,
button,
button:hover,
.anime,
.small_btn,
.btn:hover .small_btn {
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Flex Framework */

.main_flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.main_flex__nowrap {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex__auto {
  flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
}

.flex__jcontent_between {
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex__jcontent_start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex__jcontent_end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex__jcontent_center {
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

.flex__jcontent_around {
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex__align-items_start {
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex__align-items_end {
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex__align-items_baseline {
  align-items: baseline;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
}

.flex__align-items_stretch {
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
}

.flex__align-items_center {
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

.flex__align-content_flex-start {
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex__align-content_flex-end {
  align-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
}

.flex__align-content_space-between {
  align-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
}

.flex__align-content_center {
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
}

.flex__align-content_space-around {
  align-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
}

.flex__align-content_stretch {
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
}

.flex__flex-grow_01 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex__flex-grow_02 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
}

.flex__flex-grow_03 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 3;
}

.flex__flex-grow_04 {
  flex-grow: 4;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 4;
}


/* colors for the containers */

.dark {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #888888;
}

.spacegrey {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.green {
  background-color: #79c277;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.928vmax;
  line-height: 1.56vmax;
  color: #cecbc8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1344px;
}


/* header settings for width and height. */

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7.13vmax;
}


/* takes the value of a parent. */

#top .wrap {
  height: inherit;
}


/* logo location. */

#logo {
  margin-left: 1.92vmax;
}


/* logo settings and location. */

#logo img {
  width: 2.86vmax;
  height: 2.91vmax;
  margin-right: 0.572vmax;
}


/* thunder style. */

#logo span {
  font-size: 1.927vmax;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* navigation style */

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 2.3vmax;
}

#menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>THUNDER</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="dark">
    <div id="top">
      <div class="wrap main_flex__nowrap flex__jcontent_between flex__align-items_center">

        <div class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center">
          <div id="logo" class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            <span>thunder</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
          <nav class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center
                        flex__jcontent_end">
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">pages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
          </nav>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужен вертикальный скроллбар, элементу с `id="menu"`, можно указать:

```css
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Прекратите тестировать сайт масштабированием и пользуйтесь
  инструментами браузера для просмотра страницы в разных разрешениях на
  разных девайсах!
- Используйте медиа запросы:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  font-size: 100%;
  outline: 0 none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

address,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
nav,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

a,
a:hover,
button,
button:hover,
.anime,
.small_btn,
.btn:hover .small_btn {
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Flex Framework */

.main_flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.main_flex__nowrap {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.flex__auto {
  flex: auto;
  -webkit-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
}

.flex__jcontent_between {
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex__jcontent_start {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex__jcontent_end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex__jcontent_center {
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

.flex__jcontent_around {
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex__align-items_start {
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex__align-items_end {
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
}

.flex__align-items_baseline {
  align-items: baseline;
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
}

.flex__align-items_stretch {
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
}

.flex__align-items_center {
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
}

.flex__align-content_flex-start {
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex__align-content_flex-end {
  align-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
}

.flex__align-content_space-between {
  align-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
}

.flex__align-content_center {
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
}

.flex__align-content_space-around {
  align-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
}

.flex__align-content_stretch {
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
}

.flex__flex-grow_01 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex__flex-grow_02 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
}

.flex__flex-grow_03 {
  flex-grow: 3;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 3;
}

.flex__flex-grow_04 {
  flex-grow: 4;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 4;
}


/* colors for the containers */

.dark {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #888888;
}

.spacegrey {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.green {
  background-color: #79c277;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.928vmax;
  line-height: 1.56vmax;
  color: #cecbc8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1344px;
}


/* header settings for width and height. */

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7.13vmax;
}


/* takes the value of a parent. */

#top .wrap {
  height: inherit;
}


/* logo location. */

#logo {
  margin-left: 1.92vmax;
}


/* logo settings and location. */

#logo img {
  width: 2.86vmax;
  height: 2.91vmax;
  margin-right: 0.572vmax;
}


/* thunder style. */

#logo span {
  font-size: 1.927vmax;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* navigation style */

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 2.3vmax;
}

#menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
  }
  #menu nav {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #top {
    height: auto;
  }
  #menu nav {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .main_flex__nowrap {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="dark">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="wrap main_flex__nowrap flex__jcontent_between flex__align-items_center">

      <div class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center">
        <div id="logo" class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
          <span>thunder</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="menu">
        <nav class="main_flex__nowrap flex__align-items_center
                        flex__jcontent_end">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">staff</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">pages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

На разрешениях экранов мобильных девайсов лучше прятать меню в "гамбургер" кнопку (но это уже другая история).